# Fast pyspark sequenceFile lookup

Tags: python, pyspark, sequencefile

I'm using a relatively small pyspark sequenceFile (~8gb) that is in the format:

```
----------------------
|ID    | binary file |
|---------------------
|ABCD  | xxxx....    |
|---------------------
|ABC3  | xxxx....    |
----------------------
```

There are ~150,000 entries

I understand mapreduce is a very fast platform that is good at quickly searching through the db and unpacking the binaries to get at the interesting data inside the files quickly.However, I don't always want to work with ALL of the files, sometimes I'm more interested in one or two files per a calculation.

So what is the best way to repeatedly access specific entries in a hadoop sequenceFile?

1. Call `RDD.lookup("ID")` (seems to take a long time for each entry)

   - I tried looking into why this was so slow, but I didn't find that functions like `sortByKey` seemed to help very much.
   - Each lookup takes ~150 seconds
2. Use `RDD.filter(xxx)` (can read many at a time, but still slow for re-accessing)
3. run `dict(RDD.collect())` (very fast, but requires tons of memory + long initial read in time)

So... This is sort of where I'm at now.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
conf = (SparkConf().setAppName("imnotsure")
        .set('spark.executor.memory', '4G')
        .set('spark.driver.memory', '10G')
        .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '10G'))
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
db = sc.sequenceFile("DIRECTORY  OF SEQUENCEFILES")
tofind = ["ABC3"]
while len(tofind) != 0:
    db.lookup("ABC3") # Takes a long time
    # Do calculations on ABC3
    # maybe return "123D", "13BF"
    tofind = ["123D", "13BF"]
    # Keep going until tofind == []
```

Note:
I'm not against switching formats, perhaps sequenceFiles are not the way to go. However, the size is nice, and this is the way the data is provided to us.

Comment: I'm not sure spark is the best way to approach this problem. Spark is meant for large, parallel processing - not single item calculations.

Comment: @pault could you maybe suggest an alternative?